# Исключить повторяющиеся значения из Dictionary

Tags: c#

Есть Dictionary, к примеру

```
IDictionary<string, List<Model>>
```

есть модель

```
public class Model 
{ 
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public byte[] Data { get; set;}
}
```

Как можно исключить повторяющиеся значения для Name во всем Dictionary? Отфильтровать существующий словарь. Повторяющиеся значения Value необходимо удалять. Т.е. если в ключе "Key1" и в ключе "Key2" в списке есть Name с одинаковым значением, то необходимо исключить это значение для ключа (не важно какого)

тестовые данные

```
{"key1", {"Name1", <data>}, {"Name2", <data>}, {"Name3", <data>}}
{"key2", {"Name4", <data>}, {"Name2", <data>}, {"Name5", <data>}}
```

результат

```
{"key1", {"Name1", <data>}, {"Name2", <data>}, {"Name3", <data>}}
{"key2", {"Name4", <data>}, {"Name5", <data>}}
```

или

```
{"key1", {"Name1", <data>}, {"Name3", <data>}}
{"key2", {"Name4", <data>}, {"Name2", <data>}, {"Name5", <data>}}
```

Comment: @Bald у него Name это св-ва значения,а не ключа. 
Причем тут ключ?

Comment: Автор,уточни конкретнее что нужно сделать. Отфильтровать существующий словарь или задать условие,перед добавлением?

Comment: @Bald причем тут байты? Если автор явно сказал,чтобы избежать повторяющихся значений св-ва Name.

Comment: @VetaLio поправил, нужно "Отфильтровать существующий словарь"

Comment: @user2455111 Другой вопрос,что делать,когда найдется повторяющее значение : 1)удалять запись ? 2) изменить значение самого Name на какое то дефолтное??

Comment: @VetaLio удалять значение Value в этом ключе

Comment: внесите уточняющую информацию в вопрос! дубликатом считаются уникальные значения `name` и только по нему?

Comment: @Bald поправил вопрос

Comment: @Bald тут будут исключены повторяющиеся значения в контексте одного ключа

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50871/discussion-between-user2455111-and-bald).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
HashSet<string> uniqueNames = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Model>> pair in dict)
{
    foreach (Model model in pair.Value.ToList())
    {
        if (!uniqueNames.Add(model.Name))
        {
            pair.Value.Remove(model);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Почему минус? комментируйте

Comment: в вашем ответе теряется привязка к ключу

Comment: @user где ж она теряется? Удаление происходит в строке `pair.Value.Remove(model);`. `uniqueModels ` нужен только для сравнивания.

Comment: сейчас проверю (PS: минус в любос случае не я ставил)

Comment: @user2455111 Подсмотрел у Bald, обновил) Нам не нужен словарь, достаточно хэш-коллекции имен

Comment: У вас делалась лишняя операция, убрал вам ее

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, так гораздо лучше смотрится, спасибо!

Answer (score 8):

Как развитие ответа Ruslan Artamonov. Чтобы не копировать список только ради того чтоб его перебрать - можно воспользоваться методом RemoveAll:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueNames = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Model>> pair in dict)
{
    pair.Value.RemoveAll(model => !uniqueNames.Add(model.Name));
}
```

Этот способ работает быстрее на длинных списках (тот ответ имел квадратичную сложность относительно длины списка - этот имеет линейную сложность).

Но если длинных списков не предполагается - лучше использовать простой вложенный цикл ради читаемости кода.

Comment: Красиво и лаконично)